# Typescript, cast by given string

Tags: javascript, typescript, casting, ecmascript-6

i have a string given by a html element i clicked on and want to cast my object to this type. how to make this without a switch case for every string?

HTML example

```
<button type="button" data-type="MyType">cast to MyType</button>
<button type="button" data-type="OtherType">caset to OtherType</button>
```

Typescript:

```
///<reference path="jquery.d.ts" />

class MyType {
  // ... some declarations for this class
}

class OtherType {
  // .. some declarations for this class
}

let obj = {
  // compatible declations with one of the classes on top
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button').on('click', function(){
    let typeString = $(this).attr('data-type');

    obj = obj as typeString; // fails
    obj = <typeString>obj // fails



    switch(typeString) {
      case 'MyType':
        obj = obj as MyType;
        break;
      case 'OtherType':
        obj = obj as OtherType;
        breaks;
    }

    // this switch case works but looks too long on working with 200 possible response types



  }
})
```

i know what type the object is because by clicking a list of objects is loaded by calling the rest api. but how to convert them?

Comment: Just curious, why are you doing this?

Comment: also.. that is not a cast as you would in other languages, it's just an assertion to help the compiler tell the determine a type. It will not create an object of that class unless it is already that.

Comment: TypeScript type annotations and checking all happen statically at compile time. It does absolutely nothing for the runtime.

Comment: i know it has no effect on the runtime but its easier to work with correct asserted objectes in big projects while developement.

Comment: Since type checking happens at compile time and you won't know what type you're dealing with until runtime, this makes no sense. If you have code which works with different types, you must type hint it as working with a union of all possible types.